# Parsing function param in bash and pass it to new function

Tags: bash

I'm trying to build a bash function that takes two arguments, and executes the first in a docker container, then greps the second argument in the output..but I can't get it to work.

This is what I've come up so far:

```
function scriptCheckData() {
    local cmd=eval "$1"

    local RESULT=$(docker exec -i "$dockerName" cmd)

    if ! echo "$RESULT" | grep "$2"; then
        echo grep failed for "$2" in: "$RESULT"
        cleanupAndExit
    fi
}
```

Function call:

```
scriptCheckData 'test.php --option 1' 'expected string'
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

Solution was to not put my var in quotes, like this:

```
function scriptCheckData() {
    local RESULT=$(docker exec -i "$dockerName" $1)

    if ! echo "$RESULT" | grep "$2"; then
        echo "grep failed for [$2] in: [$RESULT]"
        cleanupAndExit
    fi
}
```

Comment: what contains $dockerName ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
local RESULT=$(docker exec -i "$dockerName" cmd)
```

with

```
local RESULT=$(docker exec -i "$dockerName" $cmd)
```

then I would suggest to use this sintax to improve output print

```
echo "grep failed for [$2] in: [$RESULT]"
```

Anyhow just to be sure that the function is really getting the parameter, you could add a debug in your script i.e.:

```
echo "cmd[$cmd]"
echo "param1[$1]"
echo "param2[$2]"
```

Regards
Claudio